# QGIS polygonize error 4 "file does not exist in the file system"?

Tags: qgis, gdal, error, polygonize, qgis-2.4

When I try to convert a raster DEM (in .asc or geotiff format) to polygons I get the error below:

> ERROR 4: `Y:/GIS/oversvmmelser/tmp/out.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.

Any idea what the problem is?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Typo in the path? `oversvmmelser`. Actually there is another path in the screen capture. It looks like QGIS eats the scandinavian characters. Use ASCII paths instead.

Comment: Thanks @user30184. that solved it. Non ASCII characters, what a rookie mistake.

Comment: One may also think that it is a bug in QGIS. Drop a mail to qgis-users mailing list. This is perhaps about the same:  http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9080

Comment: well you are right. But in my experience this is a generic GIS bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@user30184 came with the solution.

the (quite common GIS) problem was that non-ASCII  characters (like æ ø å) in the path name gets deleted.

**only use ASCII characters in file paths.**

Comment: ... and in your windows user name too!